# Multi threaded TCP server in Java does not reply TCP Client in C

Tags: java, c, multithreading, tcpclient, tcpserver

I'm trying to test a Multi threaded TCP MuxServer in Java with a TCP client coded in C. below the code of the part which manages the communication with the client:

```
class Echo_TCP_Thread extends Thread
{
  Socket Sock_Thr;

  public Echo_TCP_Thread (Socket The_Socket)
    {
      this.Sock_Thr = The_Socket;
    }

  public void run()
    {
      try 
    {
      PrintWriter output  = new PrintWriter(Sock_Thr.getOutputStream());
          InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(Sock_Thr.getInputStream());
      BufferedReader binput  = new BufferedReader(input);
      //
      System.out.println ("Test 1"); //This message is displayed
      //

      String temp;

      while ((temp=binput.readLine()) != null)
        {
//
      System.out.println ("Test 2"); //This message is not displayed
//
          output.print(this.getName() + " answer -> ");
          output.println(temp);
          output.flush();
      System.out.println ("Child Server : " + Thread.currentThread()  
            + " has received"  + temp);

        }   
    }
      catch (Exception e)
    {
      return;
    }
      finally
    {
      try 
        {
          Sock_Thr.close();
              System.out.println 
        ("Child Server " + Thread.currentThread()  + " : End !!! ");
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Even if I get connectivity and the end message is displayed in the client when I finish the communication, the client doesn't receive the echo messages from the server. I have checked with the `Test` messages that the program is not going into the `while ((temp=binput.readLine()) != null)` loop, but the message `Test 1` is displayed right after I get connected to the server. What should I code to correct this?

Comment: This is going to be 'waiting for a newline that is not sent by the peer'.

Comment: What is the communication protocol between client and server?

Comment: @Raedwald, it's Telnet.

Comment: @MartinJames, shouldn't the `while ((temp=binput.readLine()) != null)` condition repeat the iteration as long as there is not a `null` character sent by the client? It is not clear for me why this condition seems to not be working...

Comment: readLine() will not return until a line is received - it's a blocking read.  Lines are terminated with Line Feed chars, (or Carriage Return, Line Feed).  No LF, no readLine() return.